# Which operators should I use in this C language test?

Tags: c, testing

> In Brazil, a person is only required to vote after the age of 18. However, at 16 this person already has the option of getting a voter registration card. If she issues the card, from this moment on she must vote. Considering the situation described, which logical operators would you use to check if a person is obligated to vote having received 2 pieces of information: age and if he/she has voter registration? Indicate which operators to use and construct the condition(s) textually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   int age
   char card
   printf("age");
   scanf("%d", &age);

   if(age>=18) {
      printf("Can vote!");
   }

   if(age<18 && age>=16){
      printf("do you have card? y or n");
      scanf("%c", &card);
      if(titulo=="y"){
         printf("can vote");
      }
      else {
         printf("cant vote");
      }
   }

   if(age<16){
      printf("cant vote");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks mostly correct to me. Biggest thing is `if(titulo=="y")`. What is `titulo`? Is that supposed to be `card`? If so, that should be `if(card=='y')`, notice the single quotes `'`, that designates a `char`, double quotes `"` are for strings. You should also change that to `if ... else if ... else`

Answer (score 1):

A few bugs.

1. The variable declarations need a `;` at the end (i.e. typos)
2. The second `scanf` needs to be `" %c"` [and *not* `"%c"`] to skip over the newline from the first `scanf`.
3. `titulo` is undefined and should be `card`
4. We want to compare the single character `card` against a *character* constant (e.g. `'y'`) and *not* a *string* constant (e.g. `"y"`).

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
// NOTE/BUG: missing semicolons
#if 0
    int age
    char card
#else
    int age;
    char card;
#endif

    printf("age");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    if (age >= 18) {
        printf("Can vote!");
    }

    if (age < 18 && age >= 16) {
        printf("do you have card? y or n");

// NOTE/BUG: this needs to account for newline on previous scanf
#if 0
        scanf("%c", &card);
#else
        scanf(" %c", &card);
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: titulo is undefined and should be card
// NOTE/BUG: we want to compare card against a _character_ constant and _not_
// a string constant
#if 0
        if (titulo == "y") {
#else
        if (card == 'y') {
#endif
            printf("can vote");
        }
        else {
            printf("cant vote");
        }
    }

    if (age < 16) {
        printf("cant vote");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Although your `if/else` ladder logic was okay, it can be streamlined a bit and if we use an additional variable to denote the ability to vote (e.g. `can`), we can eliminate some replicated `printf` calls:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int age;
    char card;
    int can;

    printf("age? ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    do {
        if (age >= 18) {
            can = 1;
            break;
        }

        if (age < 16) {
            can = 0;
            break;
        }

        printf("do you have card? y or n ");
        scanf(" %c", &card);

        can = (card == 'y');
    } while (0);

    if (can)
        printf("Can vote!\n");
    else
        printf("can't vote\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that your question was _only_ in the title. The text was just a problem statement. I was able to answer the question, but, it would be better to state in the text _what_ problems you were having

Comment: thanks a lot! I've just started to take programming classes and it's been a challenging experience, but your answer really helped me. I'll look foward to improving my questions formatting.